# Construct NET::HTTP header files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I am required to make an http request with a header similar to the one quoted below.

```
POST /approval HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:text/xml
Content-Length:569
Host:127.0.0.1
Authorization: WSSE realm="SDP", profile="UsernameToken"
X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", PasswordDigest=" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", Nonce=" xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", Created="2012-07-26T11:31:26Z"
X-RequestHeader: request ServiceId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx", TransId=" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , LinkId="xxxxxxxxxx", FA="xxxxxxxxxx"
Cookie: sessionid=default8fcee064690b45faa9f8f6c7e21c5e5a
Msisdn: 861111111
X-HW-Extension: k1=v1;k2=v2
<ns2:preapprovalrequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com">
<fromfri>ID:2341305205559/MSISDN</fromfri>
<tofri>ID:2341305205559/MSISDN</tofri>
<message>abc</message>
</ns2:preapprovalrequest>
```

I have attempted to make the Net::HTTP Ruby 2.2.0 library with something similar to this.

```
url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/xxx/xxx/approval'
request_xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns2:approvalrequest xmlns:ns2='http://www.xxxxxxxx.com'><fromfri></fromfri><tofri></tofri><message></message></ns2:approvalrequest>"
uri = URI(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.content_type = 'text/xml'
req['Authorization']['/']="WSSE"
req['Authorization']['realm']= "xxxxx"
req['Authorization']['profile']="xxxxxxxx"
req['X-WSSE']['/']="UsernameToken"
req['X-WSSE']['Username']=""
req['X-WSSE']['PasswordDigest']=""
req['X-WSSE']['Nonce']=""
req['X-WSSE']['Created']=""
req['X-RequestHeader']['/']="request"
req['X-RequestHeader']['ServiceId']=""
req['X-RequestHeader']['TransId']=""
req['X-RequestHeader']['LinkId']=""
req['X-RequestHeader']['FA']=""
req.body = request_xml
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```

However, this throws errors `**NoMethodError: undefined method`[]=' for nil:NilClass.**`on the line`**req['Authorization']['/']="WSSE"**`.Any idea how to construct a proper header file with multiple fields.

Comment: Can you compare the output of `req.each_header { |n,v| puts "#{n} = #{v}" }` (place it just before making the actual request) with your desired headers? Also, what error does it throw?

Comment: `this throws errors` exactly what kind of errors?

Comment: @phoet , please check edit

Answer (score 1):

you are operating on an empty hash, either merge into it or assign it properly

```
require 'net/http'

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new('bla')
req.content_type = 'text/xml'
req['Authorization'] = {
  '/' => "WSSE",
  'realm' => "xxxxx",
  'profile' =>"xxxxxxxx",
}
puts req['Authorization'] # => {"/"=>"WSSE", "realm"=>"xxxxx", "profile"=>"xxxxxxxx"}
```